# getServerSideProps working fine in dev mode but fails in production but useSWR works fine

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js, production-environment, vercel

I have this simple code in my nextjs. I'm getting my data properly when I'm in dev mode but as soon as I deployed it to production using vercel I was getting the "request failed with error 503" error. But when I'm doing the same with the useSWR (client side fetching it works all fine).

```
import { GetServerSideProps, NextPage } from "next";
import axios from 'axios';

type Props = {
  data: any;
  error: any;
};

const Home: NextPage<Props> = ({ data, error }) => {
  if (error) return <div>{error}</div>;
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center min-h-screen py-2">
      {data.map((blog: any) => (
        <div key={blog._id}>
          <h1>{blog.title}</h1>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.CLIENT_URL/api/v1/blogs/random`);
    // res.data = {status: "success", data: blogs}
    console.log(res.data);

    return {
      props: {
        data: res.data.data,
      },
    };
  } catch (err: any) {
    return {
      props: {
        error: err.message,
      },
    };
  }
};
```

Could someone please address the issue of why this won't work in production?

Comment: Where is the call to `127.0.0.1:5000`? And when do you say "my locahost:5001 is running just fine" you say in the cloud environment too, right?

Comment: I've edited the question! I'm sorry about the prev one! I've realized from 'https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/35532' this discussion that local host won't run. But I've changed the URL to the actual server but error is "request failed with 503"

Comment: Your backend is probably logging something for that 503 error. It should provide us with some leads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guy's I've found the solution (after two days of battle). So, basically, when you deploy something to vercel it creates a backend server for your website. Here what happened was when vercel's backend server is making requests to my Linux backend server it isn't accepting/allowing those requests due to some security reasons (well, it's a Linux server after all).